# Including node_modules in Babel

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am trying to *include* my `node_modules` so that `Babel` transpiles them along with my src files.

The background of this is this: I have a `monorepo` with multiple packages, but I do not want to setup a `Webpack`/ `Babel` thing for every single package. So my idea was to tell `Webpack`/ `Babel` in my main project to transpile its `node_modules` that are imported by my sources.

I read for this I need to do this to tell `Babel` to not ignore my `node_modules`:

```
require('babel-register')({
  ignore: false
});
```

Now this gives me errors because there are a lot of packages that are not mine and that don't play along with `Babel`. But I can also tell `Babel` to only include specific packages, which I do like this:

```
require('babel-register')({
  only: /@elmc/
});
```

Because my packages are scoped under `@elmc/package-name`. This solves the issue above but now my own package still won't get transpiled. I get an error saying:

> .-collection-browser/CollectionBrowser.js Module parse failed:
>   Unexpected token (23:13) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.
>
> ```
> |   render() {
> |       return <div>asd</div>;
> |   }
> ```

He doesn't seem to transpile my `JSX` and instead throws an error. I put my `babel-register` call in my `Webpack` config. I got my `Webpack` config from `create-react-app` so it is quite lengthy, but here it is in its entirety:

https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/fe84a563ec9268dee32204d429763d5b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it working now, this comment explained it:

https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/487#issuecomment-302341620

> 1. Set resolve.symlinks to false. This is needed for the next step.
> 2. Add
>      /@foo/ regex to the include array of the rule that uses
>      babel-loader. Since we turned off symlinks resolving in the previous
>      point, other packages from the monorepo are going to resolve to
>      node_modules/@foo/, not ../. This was
>      suggested in next.js issue, so I just went to see how they
>      implemented it and did something similar.
> 3. Change node_modules in
>      resolve.modules to path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules').
>      Otherwise webpack 2 tried to require dependencies from the
>      node_modules of local linked packages. But that's probably because I
>      use file:../bar for specifying them in package.json, as I don't
>      publish them anywhere.
> 4. Set up Jest to transpile files under the @foo
>      scope. This means adding "transformIgnorePatterns":
>      ["/node_modules/(?!@foo)"] to Jest's configuration.
>      facebook/jest#2550

However, I had to not do step 3 and also this does not work quite well after all because I have to restart my Webpack dev server every time I make changes to my dependencies. So I guess the answer to this question is: "Here is how to do it, but it the only possible result (this solution) does not quite work"