# script error SCRIPT1002: in ie while running vuejs app

Tags: vuejs2

Error in console:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

Line in debugger (app.js):

```
eval("\n\nconst Apply = Function.prototype.apply;…{ - long string - }…})
```

How can I solve this issue? It works with other browsers correctly. It is not converting babel.

Comment: Are you including any third party `.vue` files from the `node_modules` folder? Code from `node_modules` is usually excluded from babel transformation. You need to tell your webpack to include those `.vue` files then.

Comment: Thanks a lot.But where do i need to write the code.Can you please tell me that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519948/including-node-modules-in-babel